# Autohotkey loop sequence with idle reset

Tags: autohotkey

I cobbled the following together from various posts:

```
keys = 0,9,8,7

loop, parse, keys, `,
{
  Key_%A_Index% := A_LoopField
  KeyCount++
}
return

XButton1::
    Rotation ++
    Send % Key_%Rotation%
    if Rotation = %KeyCount%
        Rotation = 0
return

#Persistent
    SetTimer, Check, 1000         ;check every second
return

Check:
If (A_TimeIdle >= 3000)
    Rotation = 0
return
```

The idea being that I press my mouse4 button and it cycles through the keys and then goes back to start, however I also wanted a loop so that if I don't press the button for 3 seconds, it resets back to the start of the sequence. The key sequence works however the idle reset doesnt and I'm not sure where to go from here to debug it.

Comment: Isn't very clear to me what you want in the Idle part. You mean 3secs Idle time exclusively related to this mouse XButton1? This `A_TimeIdle` that youre using is sensible to any action even a simple mouse move (by the user or by script) resets it to zero.

Comment: yes it was just the XButton1 idle time I wanted. I think I laboured under a misaprehension that A_TimeIdle represented the loop function idle time, and if it wasn't called for 3 seconds it would reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You must let the `#Persistent SetTimer, Check, 1000` part before the first `return`.

2- `A_TimeIdle` is sensible to any input, even a simple mouse move (by user or by script) resets it to zero. If you want to get the Idle time of this single hotkey use `A_TimeSinceThisHotkey` instead:

```
Check:
if (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 3000)
{
    Rotation = 0
}
return
```

Comment: this sounds like it should work but doesn't, even if i add a MsgBox instead of the Rotation assignment it doesn't get called